# Elasticsearch not assigning shards to a (new) node

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an issue with my cluster not balancing shards with a restarded node which is now empty.

1. I stopped  `my_node` from `my_cluster` and waited the shards and
   replicas to be reallocted. This succeded.
2. Then I restarted `my_node`, but the cluster didn't allocated it any shard.
3. A new index was created and the cluster assigned shards to `my_node`.
4. One day later, the node has still only shards of the new index.

Is there a way to force equal balancing of shards over nodes ?
In my case I tested a restart of a node after triggering `gateway.recover_after_time`, but this issue leads me to think :

- What should I do if I add a new node and want to trigger a rebalancing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM,
It appears that `my_node` is an older version and elasticsearch refuses to reallocate if the version to an older version.

I ran  `curl -XPOST '10.10.1.4:9200/_cluster/reroute' -d '{ "commands" : [ { "allocate" : { "index" : "my_cluster", "node" : "my_node", "shard" : 0 } } ] }'`
and the cluster answered:

> {
>
> "error" :
> "RemoteTransportException[[es-master][inet[/10.10.1.14:9300]][cluster:admin/reroute]];
>
> nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[[allocate] allocation of
> [my_cluster][0] on node
> [my_node][o7-MlqgXTU-51t4O7iBu6g][my_node][inet[10.10.1.4/10.10.1.4:9300]]{max_local_storage_nodes=1, master=true} is not allowed, reason:
>
> [YES(shard is not allocated to same node or host)]
>
> [YES(node passes include/exclude/require filters)]
>
> [YES(primary is already active)]
>
> [YES(below shard recovery limit of [2])]
>
> [YES(allocation disabling is ignored)]
>
> [YES(allocation disabling is ignored)]
>
> [YES(no allocation awareness enabled)]
>
> [YES(total shard limit disabled: [-1] <= 0)]
>
> [NO(target node version [1.6.0] is older than source node version [1.6.1])]
>
> [YES(enough disk for shard on node, free: [478.1gb])]
>
> [YES(shard not primary or relocation disabled)]
>
> ]; ",
>
> "status" : 400
>
> }